# Kafka-streams state dir io error

Tags: apache-kafka, rocksdb, apache-kafka-streams

Below error is given after stream run for certain time ? I am not able to find who is responsible for creating .sst file ?

> Env:
>
> Kafka version 0.10.0-cp1
>
> scala 2.11.8

```
    org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.ProcessorStateException: Error while executing flush from store agg
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.RocksDBStore.flushInternal(RocksDBStore.java:424)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.RocksDBStore.flush(RocksDBStore.java:414)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.MeteredKeyValueStore.flush(MeteredKeyValueStore.java:165)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorStateManager.flush(ProcessorStateManager.java:330)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.commit(StreamTask.java:247)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.commitOne(StreamThread.java:446)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.commitAll(StreamThread.java:434)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.maybeCommit(StreamThread.java:422)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:340)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:218)
Caused by: org.rocksdb.RocksDBException: IO error: /tmp/kafka-streams/pos/0_0/rocksdb/agg/000008.sst: No such file or directory
        at org.rocksdb.RocksDB.flush(Native Method)
        at org.rocksdb.RocksDB.flush(RocksDB.java:1329)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.RocksDBStore.flushInternal(RocksDBStore.java:422)
        ... 9 more
[2016-06-24 11:13:54,910] ERROR Failed to commit StreamTask #0_0 in thread [StreamThread-1]:  (org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread:452)
org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.ProcessorStateException: Error while batch writing to store agg
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.RocksDBStore.putAllInternal(RocksDBStore.java:324)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.RocksDBStore.flushCache(RocksDBStore.java:379)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.RocksDBStore.flush(RocksDBStore.java:411)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.MeteredKeyValueStore.flush(MeteredKeyValueStore.java:165)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorStateManager.flush(ProcessorStateManager.java:330)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.commit(StreamTask.java:247)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.commitOne(StreamThread.java:446)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.commitAll(StreamThread.java:434)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.shutdown(StreamThread.java:248)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:228)
Caused by: org.rocksdb.RocksDBException: IO error: /tmp/kafka-streams/pos/0_0/rocksdb/agg/000008.sst: No such file or directory
        at org.rocksdb.RocksDB.write0(Native Method)
        at org.rocksdb.RocksDB.write(RocksDB.java:546)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.RocksDBStore.putAllInternal(RocksDBStore.java:322)
        ... 9 more
```

Answer (score 6):

RocksDB is used internally by Kafka Streams to handle operator state -- and RocksDB write some files to disk.

Is it possible, that somebody deleted stuff in `/tmp` folder, and thus deleted the state of your Kafka Streams application? If yes, configure a different state store location using parameter `state.dir` (see http://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide.html#optional-configuration-parameters)

Comment: Yeah this seems to say it all: `Caused by: org.rocksdb.RocksDBException: IO error: /tmp/kafka-streams/pos/0_0/rocksdb/agg/000008.sst: No such file or directory`

Comment: @rahul-shukla Did this answer your question? If yes, feel free to accept and/or upvote.

Comment: @matthias-j-sax Could you clarify what happens in case of state dir is cleared on restart? Does it lead to inconsistent behavior for kafka streams app for the next run? Should the state be preserved carefully be developer? I could not find mentioning this on Confluent docs.

Comment: By default the state is also backed by a changelog topic in the Kafka cluster. The local RocksDB is basically a cache -- if RocksDB is lost, Kafka Streams can recreate the state from the changelog topic: https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/architecture.html#fault-tolerance